# How to alter Wordpress global post title using php

Tags: php, wordpress, global

I know i can use:

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->is_page = true;
```

For example to set the global is_page conditional to true.

Can i change the global post title in a similar way so it would effect the `the_title()` returned value?

**To clarify things:**

I need for a use of a "virtual page" case, where no post is actually loaded and i don't want to use any existing post title. just inject some custom title to the current globals so i will get it when using the_title on the current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it. gladly it's very simple :) but this piece of code will also create all other post vars for a "fake post/page":

```
$post_id = -99; // negative ID, to avoid clash with a valid post
$post = new stdClass();
$post->ID = $post_id;
$post->post_title = 'Some title or other';
$wp_post = new WP_Post( $post );
wp_cache_add( $post_id, $wp_post, 'posts' );
global $wp, $wp_query;
$wp_query->post = $wp_post;
$wp_query->posts = array( $wp_post );
$wp_query->queried_object = $wp_post;
$wp_query->queried_object_id = $post_id;
$wp_query->is_404=false;
$wp_query->is_page=true;
$GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $wp_query;
$wp->register_globals();
```

[More details here!](https://barn2.co.uk/create-fake-wordpress-post-fly/)

Answer (score 1):

To modify the title you can use a build in hook of wordpress:

```
function suppress_if_blurb( $title, $id = null ) {

    if ( in_category(' blurb', $id ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'suppress_if_blurb', 10, 2 );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear enough. i will update my question. i don't want to change specific post title. just the current page (which doesn't load any post) the_title value.

Comment: "which doesn't load any post" i dont understand this, every page that wordpress serve is a Post (expect search.php)

Comment: You can google "Wordpress virtual page". i just think this question isn't the place to explain this topic.

Comment: So íve read this article (https://www.exratione.com/2016/04/wordpress-4-create-virtual-pages-in-code-without-page-database-entries/) and if i understand it right just dont use the_title on your custom template php file. the_title needs a post-Object to display a title

Comment: I do need to use it (long explanation). any way that's not an answer (How can i do that? just don't.). you can answer "you can't do it" and it's a legitimate answer if it is true, but if it is possible i want to know how. to know i can just not do it i already know :)

Comment: Okay... you can use it but the way to archive this might be a very ugly hack: Set the title on the global $post-object and then use the_title() ... but its might be stupid to do so...